# Error trying to access Environment Cache

Tags: apigee

I'm provisioning a new environment cache on 14.04 .

When I use a Proxy API that works with the environment cache on 14.01, I get this error:

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.NoAvailableHostsException: 
NoAvailableHostsException: [host=None(0.0.0.0):0, latency=0(0), attempts=0]No hosts to borrow from",
"detail":{"errorcode":"Internal Server Error"}}}
```

Thoughts on what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The exception appears to be a temporary issue that happens at times during release cycles. Is this issue still happening or has it resolved itself?

Comment: This is still happening